# XPATH help needed for text()

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="from"> 
  <span class="label">Reported by: Rhjj, 
    <span class="ocation">US</span>
  </span> <span class="dat">  </span> </div>
```

Here I just want the output as "Reported by :Rhjj". But when i use the XPATH as
//div[contains(@class,"from")]//span[contains(@class,"label")] "US" also gets selected.
Is there any other way to select only Reported by: Rhjj, other than using text() and using substring_before comma. Even this is not consistent

//div[contains(@class,"fromTime")]//span[contains(@class,"label")]/text()

Comment: Specify the index of required text node `//div[@class="from"]/span[@class="label"]/text()[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The text you want is the first node under the `span` element with an attribute named `class` (note I've taken the names from the XML, not your code.). This works for the snippet of XML you've provided.

```
/div[@class="from"]/span[@class="label"]/node()[1]
```